# Need to add floating action button error Multiple root tags in fragment page in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I want to add a floating action button on xml page but in that I have the bellow fragment and when i add acction xml coding it saying multiple root tags reuired help to solve this.

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.findme.vysystems.googlemaps1.MapsActivity"

        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment 
             xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/map"
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.findme.vysystems.googlemaps1.MapsActivity" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
             android:id="@+id/fab"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
             android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
             android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: app crash with : error .vysystems.googlemaps1, PID: 12883
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference

Comment: one min. i will post

Comment: The error "'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear()' on a null object reference" means that you are calling the clear() method on a GoogleMap object that is actually null. please check this